# delete a trigger sqlite

Tags: sqlite

How do i delete a trigger in sqlite?

Comment: sqlite-doc-3410100/lang_createtrigger.html says in "2. Description": "*Triggers are removed using the DROP TRIGGER statement.*" ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [DROP TRIGGER statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptrigger.html):

```
DROP TRIGGER triggerNameHere;
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`DROP TRIGGER`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptrigger.html) statement.

Answer (score 3):

Use this syntax in order not to get an error if trigger does not exist:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS triggerName
```